# Django Category Model and Template View Issue

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

My question is two phased but it's from the same Django Model. I am trying to get my Category model to work properly with my Petition model. Currently,

I get this 'FieldError' error when I define a queryset for my 'CategoryView' class:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'created_on' into field. Choices are: description, id, petition, slug, title
```

Here is the code for the 'CategoryView' class:

```
class CategoryView(generic.ListView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'petition/category.html'
    context_object_name = 'category_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Category.objects.order_by('-created_on')[:10]
```

Here is the code in my models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=90, default="Select an appropriate category")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/categories/%s/"%self.slug

class Petition(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 90, default="Enter petition title here")
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=False, upload_to=imageupload)
    video = models.CharField(max_length=600, default="Enter an external video link")
    petition = models.TextField(null=False, default="Type your petition here")
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.like_set.count()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title[:50]

    def get_signatures(self):
        return self.signature_set.all()
```

I get the 'FieldError' on my category view template (category.html) when the 'get_queryset()' has been defined.

When I comment it out, the page displays but posts are not retrieved; I get a list of the categories instead. Here is my category view template(category.html):

```
{% include 'layout/header.html' %}
{% load humanize %}

    <div class="container content">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 post-area">
    {% if category_list %}
{% for petition in category_list %}
<div class="petition-block">
<h2 class="home-title"><a href="{% url 'detail' pk=petition.id %}">{{petition.title}}</a></h2>
<span class="petition-meta">
Created {{petition.created_on|naturaltime}} by 
{% if petition.created_by == user %}
You 
{% else %}
@{{ petition.created_by }}
{% endif %} 
    {% if petition.created_by == user %}
    <a href="{% url 'editpetition' pk=petition.id %}">Edit</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% if petition.created_by == user %}
    <a href="{% url 'deletepetition' pk=petition.id %}">Delete</a>
    {% endif %}
</span>

    {% if petition.image %}
        <img src="{{ petition.image.url }}" alt="petition image" class="img-responsive" />
    {% endif %}

</div><!--//petition-block-->
{% endfor %}

{% else %}

    <p>Sorry, there are no posts in the database</p>

{% endif %}
</div>


<div class="col-md-4">
<h3>Topics</h3>
<ul>
    {% for petition in category_list %}
    <li><a href="#">{{petition.title}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are trying to order the Category's queryset by created_on and your Category model doesn't have any field called created_on. That field is within Petition model.  If you want to order the categories by petition's created_on you should do a "join" between tables, but with Django's ORM is easy.

For simplicity on your code is better to name the relation

```
class Petition(models.Model):
    ...
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='petitions')
    ...
```

Now you can refer to the category's petitions as 'petitions'

```
Category.objects.order_by('-petitions__created_on')
```

For use the petitions within the template the best way is prefetch the petitions on the queryset to avoid hitting the database every time in the for loop.

```
Category.objects.prefetch_related('petitions').order_by('-petitions__created_on')
```

That would bring every petition for each category. So in your template you can use:

```
{% for category in category_list %}
    {% for petition in category.petitions.all %}
        ...
        @{{ petition.created_by }}
        ...
    {% end for %}
{% end for %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The value returned in my query set with what you suggested and I am still getting the same error: `Cannot resolve keyword 'petition_set__created_on' into field.`

Comment: Okay, I changed it to: 
`def get_queryset(self):
  return Category.objects.order_by('-petition__created_on')[:10]` and it's loading fine now except that the template (category.html) is still returning the category lists instead of displaying the posts in the category

Comment: Ahh that's because you are only passing the categories to the template. Look how the listview works http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.9/django.views.generic.list/ListView/. I'll edit the answer to complete your question

Comment: I got another error: `Cannot find 'petition' on Category object, 'petition' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()`